# Is there a way to pin my github gists to keep at the top

Tags: github, bookmarks, gist

Is there a way to pin my github gists at the top, Some gist are frequently used and updated.
A Pin at the top make it easy to access.

Currently I keep a browser bookmark for easy visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Sort** dropdown for recently updated gists otherwise, there is no other feature like *pin* or *star* yet provided by github.